# Why does a nested block item change the marker alignment on Firefox vs Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, html-lists

This particular code below has a different render in Firefox vs Chrome.

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/"><div>test</div></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Firefox vs Chrome:
[image: Top is Firefox, bottom is Chrome]

Because of the `block` type of the div, The anchor element is not aligned with the marker on Firefox, but is on Chrome.

Any idea why ?

Comment: a bug probably .

Comment: What's the goal of a div in an anchor? Why not use CSS instead?

Comment: Marker boxes are just poorly defined in CSS. You wouldn't believe how many differences between Chrome and Firefox there exist with marker boxes. Generally marker boxes are treated as inline-level boxes, which would mean that a block element following would start a new line. It seems that Chrome is treating the marker box as a run-in box.

Comment: Safari behaves like Chrome btw.